# Great answers are shy!

Tags: bug, answers, design, profile-page

Just a minute ago I went to answers of my profile and found that my top answer became a bit shy:

> [image]

Then I figured out that it happens with any answers with score>100:

> [image]

Please unshy them!

<sup>By mistake I used different green on my two images, sorry - it is online editor and I closed it after the first image and then reopened, so I couldn't use the same color</sup>

Comment: No repro with clean Chrome. What browser? Any extensions or plugins, messing with CSS? (e.g. SOUP)

Comment: @Sha Reproed in last Chrome on Android and Safari 7.1 on Mac, so I thought its not only my bug...

Comment: Dunno only yours, but can't see any shyness on profiles here. :/

Comment: No repro in IE11 because I don't have answers with a score >100 ...

Comment: @rene Go to any user having answers with score>100.

Comment: Ok, On shog9 profile I have a repro in IE11 on Win7/x64

Comment: They move down due to the excess weight of so many upvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new profile page design seems to correctly sort this problem out:

> [image]

So, when every SE site gets new profile pages, this issue will be gone completely.